# C# Expression.Eq() para multiples diferentes valores incluyendo nulos?

Tags: c#

Tengo un código como el siguiente:

```
            var test1 = (ExclusionReasonPharmacy[])ActiveRecordBase.FindAll(typeof(ExclusionReasonPharmacy), new Order[] { Order.Asc("Description") }, Expression.Eq("Status", 'A'), Expression.Eq("CustomerType", CustomerType.Find(2)));
            var test2 = (ExclusionReasonPharmacy[])ActiveRecordBase.FindAll(typeof(ExclusionReasonPharmacy), new Order[] { Order.Asc("Description") }, Expression.Eq("Status", 'A'), Expression.Like("Profile", "ALL"), Expression.Eq("CustomerType", CustomerType.Find(2)));
            var test3 = (ExclusionReasonPharmacy[])ActiveRecordBase.FindAll(typeof(ExclusionReasonPharmacy), new Order[] { Order.Asc("Description") }, Expression.Eq("Status", 'A'), Expression.Eq("Profile", null), Expression.Eq("CustomerType", CustomerType.Find(2)));
```

En mi variable **test1** obtengo toda la lista de rows que están en la tabla lo cual está bien.
En mi variable **test2** agrego la expression Like para profile y me devuelve 1 registro lo cual está bien.
En mi variable **test3** quiero devolver los valores que tengan null en ese campo pero no devuelve nada por más que sepa que esos registros existen.

Mi pregunta es:

Cómo puedo hacer que el Eq identifique un valor null y cómo debo hacer si quiero por ejemplo filtrar por "Profile" pero que sea nulo y que sea "ALL" ?

Comment: Todo ese código para que es? Que es lo que quieres hacer? Quizá puede hacerse de otra forma

Comment: simplemente obtiene un array de entidades instanciadas por base por cada registro que exista en la tabla. Es decir, un array de objetos sobre el que quiero filtrar utilizando el metodo Expression.Eq(). pero cuando filtro por valor null no devuelve nada. Tampoco se bien como usar el Expression.And si quisiera filtrar por 2 valores.

Comment: Well half of the problem solved. This works for null value : Expression.IsNull("Profile") .